# Converting Decimal to Binary in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, binary

I found out this snippet of code which works, but I do not understand why it does. It converts an Int to its representation in binary.

```
repBinario::Int -> Int
repBinario 0 = 0
repBinario x = 10 * repBinario (x `div` 2) + x `mod` 2
```

I know what `div` and `mod` do. However, how does it place each number that comes from `mod` together?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @melpomene I wanted to know what happend each time `repBinario` was being called, this recursion was a little bit confusing for a newbie like me. The answers below we're really useful though.

Comment: The answers we're very helpful, I did not choose just one because some people might not be looking for the same thing that I was, anyway, I decided to upvote each reply since all of them structured the problem in a different way and so the question resulted in diversed solutions, all equally interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

In short, it multiplies the accumulated result by `10` on each iteration.

To get a clearer understanding of what's going on we can divide your function into two simpler ones. The first one will convert an integer into a list of binary digits. The other will then do exactly the thing that bothers you: concat a list of binary digits into an integer.

```
extractBinDigits :: Int -> [Int]
extractBinDigits =
  unfoldr (\x -> if x == 0 then Nothing else Just (mod x 2, div x 2))

concatDigits :: [Int] -> Int
concatDigits =
  foldr (\a b -> a + b * 10) 0
```

As you see we simply fold the list multiplying the accumulator by `10` on each step and adding each digit to it.

Then your original function becomes just this:

```
repBinario :: Int -> Int
repBinario =
  concatDigits . extractBinDigits
```

Division now lets us inspect and reuse the finer pieces of our program providing us with greater flexibility. E.g., by adding another simple function you can now convert the integer into a string in one go:

```
showDigits :: [Int] -> String
showDigits =
  reverse . map (chr . (+ 48))

repStringyBinario :: Int -> String
repStringyBinario =
  showDigits . extractBinDigits
```

Answer (score 5):

Let’s go through an example, then:

```
repBinario 5
```

Substitute definition of `repBinario 5`:

```
10 * repBinario (5 `div` 2) + 5 `mod` 2
```

Reduce `div` and `mod`:

```
10 * repBinario 2 + 1
                    ^
```

Here we have produced our first digit, marked with `^`.

Substitute definition of `repBinario 2`:

```
10 * (10 * repBinario (2 `div` 2) + 2 `mod` 2) + 1
                                                 ^
```

Reduce `div` and `mod`:

```
10 * (10 * repBinario 1 + 0) + 1
                          ^    ^
```

Substitute definition of `repBinario 1`:

```
10 * (10 * (10 * repBinario (1 `div` 2) + 1 `mod` 2) + 0) + 1
                                                       ^    ^
```

Reduce `div` and `mod`:

```
10 * (10 * (10 * repBinario 0 + 1) + 0) + 1
                                ^    ^    ^
```

Substitute definition of `repBinario 0`:

```
10 * (10 * (10 * 0 + 1) + 0) + 1
                     ^    ^    ^
```

Reduce:

```
101
```

At each step, `` (`mod` 2) `` gets the least significant binary digit, and `` (`div` 2) `` shifts the number *rightward*, discarding the digit and passing the rest of the number recursively to `divBinario`. At the end, we do the opposite process: `(+ d)` adds the current digit to the result, and `(* 10)` shifts the number *leftward* so we can add more digits.

What you get is a decimal number that *looks* identical to the binary representation of the original input.

If you remove the multiplication by `10`, you get `popCount`, a function that gives you the *population count* of a number—the number of `1` bits in its binary representation:

```
popCount 0 = 0
popCount x = popCount (x `div` 2) + x `mod` 2

popCount 5  ==  2
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be best to calculate this function for a small value by hand - this is possible since this is a pure function therefore you can replace left hand side with its definition (i.e. right hand side) - the fancy computer science word for this feature is "referential transparency".

```
repBinario 24 = 10 * repBinario (24 `div` 2) + 24 `mod` 2
              = 10 * repBinario 12 + 0
              = 10 * (10 * repBinario (12 `div` 2) + 12 `mod` 2)
              = 100 * repBinario 6 + 0
              = 100 * (10 * repBinario (6 `div` 2) + 6 `mod` 2)
              = 1000 * repBinario 3 + 0
              = 1000 * (10 * repBinario (3 `div` 2) + 3 `mod` 2)
              = 10000 * repBinario 1 + 1000 * 1
              = 10000 (10 * repBinario (1 `div` 2) + 1 `mod` 2) + 1000
              = 10000 (10 * repBinario 0 + 1) + 1000
              = 10000 (10 * 0 + 1) + 1000
              = 10000 * 1 + 1000
              = 11000
```

in those steps I just evaluated the function by its definition and used the fact that integer-addition/multiplication obey the law of distribution.